# Debugging a segfault in Perl

Tags: perl, segmentation-fault, perl-module

I'm trying to debug a segfault I'm getting from Perl.

I'm using:

- Perl 5.8.8
- Net::SSH2 0.45
- Libssh2 1.4.2
- Openssl 0.9.8x (but I've also have the same problem with 1.0.1c)

The problem happens when I call:

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH2->new();
```

I've run it with the Perl debugger (`perl -d`) and stepped through into Net::SSH2 and it segfaults at the line:

```
my $self = $class->_new;
```

The output after the segfault is unhelpful:

```
zsh: segmentation fault  perl -d ./test.pl
```

Running with `strace` ends with:

```
open("<snip>/perl/lib/perl5.8/Linux-2.6c2.5-x86_64-64int/Net/SSH2/Listener.pm", O_RDONLY) = 4
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7fffb9cdc920) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
read(4, "package Net::SSH2::Listener;\n\nus"..., 4096) = 804
lseek(4, 90, SEEK_SET)                  = 90
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 90
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

Now I'm stuck. What do I do next? How do I dig deeper to find out what is wrong?

The only thing I can't change is that I must use Perl 5.8.8 (I have no choice in the matter).

---

`gdb` output from method suggestd by PSIAlt:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000379ea141dc in __longjmp () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000379ea141dc in __longjmp () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#1  0x0101f58e4fc7bacc in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0x101f58e475b223b
(gdb)
```

So, not much help...

Again, my real question is "what next?"

Comment: `gdb` will tell you more, especially the output of its `bt`. A debug build is useful, but not required.

Comment: Just FYI: all segfaults i saw in Perl is comed from XS module(s). This **strace** explains nothing since he read package file, close handle... and just die. Need to run your program from **gdb**: run `gdb perl` type `set args perl.pl`; type `run`. Post output from `bt` command.

Comment: @PSIAlt: Updated with gdb output.

Comment: @bahamat Not very helpful tho.. Maybe its worth to try update/reinstall modules..

Comment: Did you tried to use a newer Perl? Maybe Perlbrew/local::lib could help you build a new Perl. This way you could check that it is working or not.

Comment: As I said, Perl 5.8.8 is a hard requirement.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me under Ubuntu 12.10 x86_64, perl 5.8.8 (as compiled by perlbrew), libssh2 1.4.2, openssl 1.0.1c and Net::SSH2 0.46.

Under Unix/Linux, [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) is probably a better choice. It can even emulate most of Net::SSH2 API through [Net::OpenSSH::Compat](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH%3a%3aCompat).

Comment: Net::OpenSSH is a good alternative suggestion. I'll try that out.

Comment: Unfortunately Net::OpenSSH (or Compat) won't work for me. All I need to do is open a socket and do auth_list, testing those for failure. Net::OpenSSH doesn't actually send any network traffic until actually logging in. It silently always succeeds the things I need :-(